# how to draw this for a beginner?

Tags: modeling

I want to draw parking space as shown below[image]

for me, perhaps there is two ways for doing this, one way is to draw a very big plane for the parking lot, and then draw the smaller plane as the individual parking space, however in this way, how to make the white parking lines or just use the texture ?

another way is just to draw a big parking lot and draw the lines on the parking lot plane.

as a beginner, i don't know Which way is the better way.

Comment: Usually the painted parts would just be a texture.  Check out my shader [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35402/5705), just use a mask for the painted areas instead of the noise/greater-than mask.

Comment: You can use a texture or another mesh. I'd go for a texture.

Comment: You can also use a single mesh, but create two separate materials, one for the ground, and one for the strips  (each one with or without textures), and assign selected faces of the mesh to each...