# Using noise texture of one object to effect another object

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have made the ground look wet by using a noise texture to control a glossy node. I am looking to add several parking lines to the ground, my thinking was to uv unwrap the lines onto planes and shrinkwrap them to the ground below. The image below shows the result.

Is it possible to have the parking lines effected by the glossy noise nodes from the ground below? Or is there a better process than the one I have described?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39469/how-to-draw-this-for-a-beginner

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is first to create your lines and join them to your plane. Use a *Texture Coordinate* node (*Object* output) that you plug into the *Texture* node you've chosen. The noise will affect both the ground and the lines, with no discontinuity.

[image]